# Is it okay to use "unsafeRunSync()" in Cats-Effects?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, doobie

I am using Doobie and [in the examples that I found](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/04-Selecting.html), it uses `unsafeRunSync`, like:

```
sql"select name from country"
  .query[String]    // Query0[String]
  .to[List]         // ConnectionIO[List[String]]
  .transact(xa)     // IO[List[String]]
  .unsafeRunSync    // List[String]
  .take(5)          // List[String]
  .foreach(println)
```

Under the hood, this function is implemented as follows:

```
final def unsafeRunSync(): A = unsafeRunTimed(Duration.Inf).get
```

[In the docs](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/io.html), I found that "Please note that this function is intended for testing; it should never appear in your mainline production code!". I wonder if it is okay then to use `unsafeRunSync` in production if it uses this function under the hood?

Also, how do I put a timeout on the execution if not with `unsafeRunTimed`?

Comment: The idea of an `IO` monad is to suspend all your side effects and compose them into a bigger `IO` that represents your whole program. At that point, you can call one of the `unsafe` methods to actually run your program. - You may also use `IOApp` that way you do not need to call either of them since that one expects an `IO` and it internally executes it  - Now, given your question, I assume you are not familiar with pure FP, if you just want to use **doobie** to run some queries, I guess the simplest for your use case is to just call `unsafeRunToFuture` on the `IO` or `unsafeRunSync`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it depends on what exactly you mean by “OK”. I am not aware of any laws restricting the use of the `unsafeRunSync` method. I also don't think any major religion considers it a sin (though some minor ones certainly might).

That said, calling `unsafeRunSync` is not referentially transparent and has all the downsides that come with that. Namely, equational reasoning goes out of the window. It also blocks the calling thread if asynchronous processing is involved at any point (and in ScalaJS it won't work at all in such cases). To me, these are sufficient reasons to avoid using it in production code whenever possible. That said, there are situations where it's not possible. For instance, you sometimes need to implement interfaces that expect side effects to be performed, such as `java.io.OutputStream`. There's not much you can do in that situation, those signatures are the way they are.

It is however not necessary to call `unsafeRunTimed` to perform an action with a timeout. Just use the [race method](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/typeclasses/concurrent.html) and a [Timer](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/timer.html).